# PLS AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'fit'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, deep-learning

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caetd.png)  I am trying to build a collaborative recommendation system the code below. I am a noob to deep learning right now, and I am stuck with this error when I try to train the model. I want to train a model with a csv data set. Can anyone please help me understand what's happening? I would really appreciate it.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import the surprise packages
from surprise import Dataset
from surprise import Reader
from surprise.prediction_algorithms.matrix_factorization import SVD as FunkSVD

# Import GridSearchCV for algorithm tuning
from surprise.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Import train_test_split
from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split

# Read in the prepared dataframe from the user_cleanup notebook
user_df = pd.read_csv('user_clean.csv')
user_df.head()

# Merge the two dataframes on appid
df = user_df.merge(games_df,on='appid')
df = df.drop('name',1)
df.head()

# Let's take a look at one of the most prominent users in the dataset, user 24469287
df[df['user_id'] == 24469287]

# Let's find this users favorite games using the 1-5 rating scale
print(f"Shape:{df[(df['user_id'] == 24469287) & (df['rating_5'] == 5)].shape}")
display(df[(df['user_id'] == 24469287) & (df['rating_5'] == 5)])

# Prepare the dataframes for the surprise package
# Dataframe needs to contain 3 columns: user id, item id, and rating
# For the 1-10 scale
rating_10_df = df.filter(['user_id','appid','rating_10'])
rating_10_df = rating_10_df.sort_values(by=['user_id','appid'])
# And the 1-5 scale
rating_5_df = df.filter(['user_id','appid','rating_5'])
rating_5_df = rating_5_df.sort_values(by=['user_id','appid'])

# Confirm dataframe is set up properly (user, item, rating)
rating_10_df.head()

# initialize the reader with 1-10 rating scale
my_reader = Reader(rating_scale=(0,10))

# load the dataframe with the reader
md = Dataset.load_from_df(rating_10_df, my_reader)

%%time

# Set the parameter grid for optimization
param_grid = {
    # Number of latent factors. More factors could give better results, but can also lead overfitting
    'n_factors': [50, 100, 150], 
    # Number of epochs. Number of iterations the algorithm will run
    'n_epochs': [10, 20, 50],
    # Learning rate. The speed at which algorithm learns. Larger values give faster learning, but smaller values give more accurate learning.
    'lr_all': [0.005, 0.1],
    'biased': [False] }

# Set GridSearchCV with 5 fold cross-validation using the FunkSVD
GS = GridSearchCV(FunkSVD, param_grid, measures=['rmse','mae','fcp'], cv=5)
# Fit the model to the data
GS.fit(md)
```

Comment: Please add the error that you are encountering.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.